# In which version of "@solana/wallet-adapter-react", I can sign and send the vesionTrasactionV0

Tags: versionedtransactions

I need to send the version transaction through phantom wallet, but could not find any method in the current version, how can I send the version transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can send transaction with Phantom by connecting your wallet using [Solana Wallet Adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter)

You can then send a transaction by following [Versioned Transactions Docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/versioned-transactions#how-create-a-versioned-transaction)

**First, get your wallet.**

```
const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
```

**Then Create the Versioned Transaction**

```
const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
let minRent = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(0);
let blockhash = await connection
  .getLatestBlockhash()
  .then((res) => res.blockhash);

// create an array with your desires `instructions`
const instructions = [
  web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: minRent,
  }),
];

// create v0 compatible message
const messageV0 = new web3.TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: payer.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: blockhash,
  instructions,
}).compileToV0Message();

const transaction = new web3.VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
```

**Then sign and send the transaction**

```
const signed = wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
connection.sendTransaction(transaction);
```